# sqlite: unique covering index

Tags: sqlite, unique-index, covering-index

Let's say I have a table t1 with three columns A, B, C, where (A,B) comprise a unique key (with hundreds of thousands of rows).  Since 90% of queries will be of the form SELECT C FROM t1 WHERE A=? and B =?, I suppose I want to have a covering index for A, B, and C.

How do I have a covering index that includes C and defines (A,B) as unique?

I'm thinking of having two indexes: one unique and one covering and using INDEXED BY to force the covering index for SELECTS.

Is this reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite 3.8.2 or later, you can make this table a [WITHOUT ROWID table](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), so that the table itself behaves like a covering index:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    A,
    B,
    C,
    PRIMARY KEY (A, B)
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's reasonable.

However, before you do that I would recommend that you try putting a primary key on A and B and try your query again. See if there is a performance gain. If there is no gain, you could certainly try to enforce uniqueness with `create unique index idx_t1_ab on t1(a,b)`. Then create an index on A, B and C.